# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

For the code

```
....

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',]

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = <My SpreadSheet>

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="A:E").execute()
values = result.get()
```

It Gives

```
  File "C:\Users\Bamgm14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)
```

I could not find an issue or Stackexchange answer so I am making the question
I am not sure what happened. I tried everything possible from trying to make a new token (which gives the same problem) to resetting my Oauth Token to no change. Please give any help you can

Comment: Do you have any proxy configured ?

Comment: No, atleast none I am aware of.